# How can one start an activity from BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I have a broadcast receiver (c2dm push receiver).
When i receive a push, i want this to happen:

- Start a notification, where you are led to StopAlarmActivity (Done!)
- If the application are in front, start StopAlarmActivity (How can i check this)

My main problem is that i can't get the broadcast receiver to start the StopAlarmActivity for me.

I have registered the broadcast receiver in the manifest.

Here's the code i use to try to start an activity:

```
Intent intentHome = new Intent(context, StopAlarmActivity.class);
          intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
          context.startActivity(intentHome);
```

This is the stacktrace message:

> 11-20 00:29:30.514: E/AndroidRuntime(13612):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver
>   com.packagename.PushReceiver: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException:
>   Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires
>   the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

I've seen some people saying it's just to add FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK to the intent, and the exception is also telling me that, so i really don't understand why it's not working.

Anyone got an idea?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your code you have:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

but your intent for this new activity is `intentHome`. Change that line to:

```
intentHome.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Comment: hmm, nop :( changed to this, but same error
Intent intentHome = new Intent(context, StopAlarmActivity.class);
       intent.setFlags(intentHome.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       context.startActivity(intentHome);

Comment: You still have it different from what I provided. `intentHome.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` Note the **`intentHome`**

Comment: haha, i seriously need some sleep now :)
Thanks for the input, it worked.